# Binding SQL data to Label in WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

Is there  a way to data bind SQL data to a label in WPF?

I have a SQL database that has a total of summed up data. I want to display the last column's data to a label. So if the column reads "10" then I need the label to display "10".

Here is the code I've tried:

C#:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myconnectioninfo);
SqlCommand scom = new SqlCommand();
scom.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 [TotalIncidents] FROM sixMonthReport ORDER BY [TotalIncidents] DESC"
Object temp = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
label.Text = temp.ToString();
```

Most appeared to work until I get to the label.text portion which is not an option in WPF.

I can't seem to find any information on much of WPF / labels any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`label` does not have a `text property` but it does have `content` one, so you can try something like:

```
Object temp = null;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myconnectioninfo))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 [TotalIncidents] FROM sixMonthReport ORDER BY [TotalIncidents] DESC", con))
    {
        temp = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
label.Content = temp?.ToString();
```

Comment: I just noticed I made an error with cmd.commandtext = section I meant to put "scom.commandtext = "

Comment: Your  `Object temp` is defined inside the `using` so you can't access it from outside ... - I just edited the answer ..

Comment: @FeDe Thanks, didn't notice